# Double integral of an absolute valued function (in polar coordinates)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having a problem separating the integral

> Calculate the integral over given region by changing to polar coordinates $$f(x,y)=|16xy|,\quad x^2+y^2\le 25.$$

I'm not really sure where to start, I know that

$x=r\cos \theta$
$y=r\sin \theta$

and that can be substituted into the equation, $|16r\cos \theta r \sin \theta|$ but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: After substitution, you get $16\int_{0<r<5}\int_{0<\theta<2\pi}r^2|\sin\theta\cos\theta|\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta=16\int_{0<r<5}r^2\mathrm{d}r\int_{0<\theta<2\pi}\frac{|\sin2\theta|}{2} \mathrm{d}\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

We can write, within the domain enclosed by $\;x^2+y^2\le25\;$ :

$$f(x,y)=|16xy|=\begin{cases}\;\;\,16xy\;,\;\;&(x,y)\in\text{first or third quadrant}\\{}\\-16xy\,,\;\;&(x,y)\in\text{ second or third quadrant}\end{cases}$$

Thus, your integral is, in polar coordinates:

$$\int_0^5\int_0^{\pi/2}16r^3\cos t\sin t\,dt\,dr+\int_0^5\int_\pi^{3\pi/2}16r^3\cos t\sin t\,dt\,dr-$$

$$-\int_0^5\int_{\pi/2}^\pi16r^3\cos t\sin t\,dt\,dr-\int_0^5\int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}16r^3\cos t\sin t\,dt\,dr$$

Comment: very helpful thanks, but was the double negative intended (between the second and third integral)

Comment: @ShaunGGG That is just one minus sign, it is only that there's a change of row so that'll be clearer (hopefully).